# Document listener for multiple text fields

Tags: java, filter, textfield, documentlistener

I have the following code:

```
 private void filter2method() {

    filterR.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {//currently the document listener is set for textfield called filterR1

          @Override
          public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
              newFilter();
          }

          @Override
          public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
              newFilter();
          }

          @Override
          public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
              newFilter();
          }

          private void newFilter() {
              RowFilter <DefaultTableModel, Object>rf =null;
              List<RowFilter<Object,Object>> rfs =
                      new ArrayList<RowFilter<Object,Object>>();

              ArrayList textAL = new ArrayList();
              String text = filterR.getText();
              textAL.add(text);
              String text1 = filterR1.getText();
              textAL.add(text1);
              String text2 = filterR2.getText();
              textAL.add(text2);


              try {
                  for (int i = 0; i < textAL.size(); i++) {
                      rfs.add(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + textAL.get(i), 2, 6, 11));
                  }

                  rf = RowFilter.andFilter(rfs);

              } catch (java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException e) {
                  return;
              }

              sorter.setRowFilter(rf);
          } }

    );
}
```

Currently the document listener is set to the textfield filterR but i want the listener to also include filterR1 and filterR2 as i have a search filter further down in the code that searches textfield filterR1 and filterR2 ie a combined filter search.

How do i change my document listener to cover more than just 1 textfield?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could assign the `DocumentListener` to a variable

```
DocumentListener docListener = new DocumentListener() {
...
};
```

And the use it for all your textfields

```
filterR.getDocument().addDocumentListener(docListener);
filterR1.getDocument().addDocumentListener(docListener);
filterR2.getDocument().addDocumentListener(docListener);
```

...